# ¿Cual es la mejor forma de pasar datos de la vista al controlador?

Tags: php, mvc

La pregunta surge porque he visto varias formas de pasar los datos de la vista al controlador en este caso con php, por ejemplo:

1. En el atributo action del form que lleve el nombre del controlador que procesará los datos(que fué como aprendí primeramente).
2. Con la etiqueta script al final del html que lleve tambien a un archivo javascript y usar ajax.
3. Creando un objeto de la clase controlador al final del formulario html (antes de cerrar la etiqueta del formulario).

Entonces cual sería la mejor forma, mas recomendada o con mas seguridad para pasar esos datos al controlador.

Saludos

Comment: Sinceramente esto es una pregunta de opinión ya que cada quién puede hacer un caso de porqué cada opción es la mejor, al final del día depende de los requerimientos que tengas la forma que vayas a resolver cada problema.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].